# Facebook login page squashed in Android webview (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin, authentication, webview

I am working on a Xamarin Forms app where I use a webview in the Android side of the project. The webview displays a page from my web site which has the Connect with Facebook button. When the user running the app on their device (or myself in the emulator) taps the Connect with Facebook button, a Facebook login page is displayed but the content is "squashed" to one side (see screenshot)

[image]

The iOS app uses a webview as well, but there is no issue with this page. The problem seems to be Android only. I tried to open the URL in the Android stock browser and the Facebook login page shows correctly. Also this happens on all tested devices with API 19 to 25. My app doesn't work for API 18 and below.

Has anyone seen this before? I cannot reproduce it outside of my app in any desktop nor mobile browser and all other pages except this one display correctly.

Comment: webview should be attributed with Height and Width properties. Have you set Height and Width of webview in Xamarin Forms ? Please ensure those properties are set.

Comment: Yes, Height and Width are set to stretch across the entire screen. The same shared code works on iOS and in Android on all other pages but the Facebook login page. You can see from the screenshot that the background covers the entire screen (except the navigation bar at the top). I think it's Facebook not resizing its content correctly but I cannot figure out how to reproduce it or fix it.